# Boot Ubuntu DVD on another Windows laptop

Tags: boot, windows

On my laptop A, I can put the Ubuntu DVD in the power-up, and get the Ubuntu menu.

Now the keyboard controller on A has failed.
So I put my Ubuntu DVD in B and powered up.

To my dismay, Windows pops up as though there were no Ubuntu DVD.

Please let me know what I can/should do to get Ubuntu on my laptop B.

Comment: This is a windows problem. Not Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind It looks more like BIOS problem, doesn’t it?

Comment: Yes, user needs to stop automatic booting and select booting from an external device. Most of the times it is F10, although it depends on the hardware/bios manufacturer.

Comment: If you tell us your notebooks' model, it would be useful. And yes, I think @Melebius is right, this seems like a BIOS problem.

Answer (score 3):

I guess laptop B is not configured to boot from dvd.  Please check your bios configuration.

Comment: boot into bios, check 'boot order' and change it to have cd/dvd before HD.